# igCombobox, how do I prevent submisson if nothing selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ignite-ui, igcombo

I have an igCombobox "checkbox", when nothing is selected it still submits the form, which I dont want to happen.

I'm using this code to submit:

```
 <div id="checkboxSelectCombo" name="kanal" style="position:absolute;" ></div>

 $("#checkboxSelectCombo").on( "focusout",function() {
  $(this).closest("form").submit();
     });
```

So, I tried to use if statement, if value is greater than zero or is not an empty string

```
$("#checkboxSelectCombo").on( "focusout",function() {
             if($(this).val()>0 || $(this).val()!=""){
  $(this).closest("form").submit();}
     });
```

But since I cant get the value  from checkboxSelectCombo it wont work.
I already searched igCombobox documentation, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. As Zdravko Kolev said that I should use dropDownClosed, I was able to prevent submit without selecting anything on the igComboBox with this code

```
 dropDownClosed: function (evt, ui) {
                var dpValue = ui.owner.value();  
                 if(dpValue != 0){                 //dpValue>0
                $(this).closest("form").submit();
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see you are submitting the form on every focus out. You can perform the submit on [selectionChanged](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igCombo#events:selectionChanged) event or [dropDownClosed](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ui.igCombo#events:dropDownClosed) for example. From these events you can access the items list or to perform some checks. Keep in mind that they are not cancellable.